# open Xlsx from database

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, browser, blob, xlsx

i'm trying to open a xlsx file witch is actually stored in database as Blob. so the process is in three steps :

1st : get file from database.

2nd : save it on server.

3rd: open it.

i tried to use **outputstream**  like this :

```
 InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream();
 OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("c:/mytemp/testanar.xlsx");
 byte[] buff = blob.getBytes(1,(int)blob.length());
 out.write(buff);
 out.close();
```

but i can't find any issue to use this method with URL.

my question is how can i save the file on server ?

Comment: *but i can't find any issue to use this method with URL*: what do you mean by that? Your code, although buggy, already saves the file on the server, doesn't it? To make it correct, and also simpler, use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-. You should explain us what you're trying to achieve, because I have the feeling this is not what you should be doing. Explain what the functionality is about, as if I was a user of your app.

Comment: okey. initially i'm trying to read file from database.

Comment: A user of an app doesn't know what a database is. Try harder than that. Something like: you click here, and then ...

Comment: okey, so we have a view that show a list of all documents that are stored in database. for each  documents we can read the document on browser or download the file.

Comment: Ah. So you don't need to store the excel file in a folder on the server. It's already in the database, so that's useless. Just write all the bytes stored in the blob to the HttpServletResponse OutputStream, after setting the appropriate content type on the response.Googling for 'download excel file with servlet" should give you many hints.

Comment: it's kinda of solution that need a specification of location. this same location must be a directory in the server to allow all the web app's users to open the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution to my problem. my problem was to find a way to open excel file using the browser in web application. 
here is the solution in 2 steps :

**1st step :**

install an extension that help you to read excel's files i use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/office-editing-for-docs-s/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj

**2nd step :**

create a servlet that help you to read your file here is a part of mine :

```
public String downloadDocument(@PathVariable int docId, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    Rapport document = rapportService.findRapportById(docId);

    response.setContentType(document.getType());
    response.setContentLength(document.getContent().length);
    // if you want to download the file instead of reading the same file 
    // remove "//" below
    //response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + document.getName() + "\"");
    FileCopyUtils.copy(document.getContent(), response.getOutputStream());

    return "redirect:listofreports";
}
```

**[EDIT]** :
where Rapport is the model that represente the excel's file.

Good luck.